# Add dynamically frames to images

Tags: php, image-processing, imagemagick

On a web server running PHP I have images like that:

[image]

To which I have to add frames like that:
[image]

I think it's quite complex, because images won't have the same ration (width/height), there is a shadow on the Mat which can be modified to change the color or can be removed.

I know how to play with php image GD library and I could easily add some watermarks on images but I don't know which tool I should use to generate dynamically a frame.

Maybe [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) or I was thinking about [Gimp bach mode](https://www.gimp.org/tutorials/Basic_Batch/). Which tool would you advise me?

Comment: If on Unix-like system, you can try my picframe script at http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/picframe/index.php. It has a number of frames, but you can add new ones if you want. Also see http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/thumbnails/#frame_edge

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do it with Imagemagick: https://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/thumbnails/#frame_edge

You just need to do the calculations and use them to create the dimensions etc. from the original image.

It gets quite complicated to work out at the start.

EDIT: This has a smaller shadow on the matt ( my personal preference ) but I did it with Imagemagick and php ( note Stackoverflow has changed it to a jpg so it has lost the background transparency ):

[image]

Comment: Yes but I am not sure to be able to use it because of the shadow on the map I need to insert.

Comment: You can do everything you need but you need to build up the image bit by bit.

Comment: Oooh you did it with PHP/Imagemagick and with a mate, can I post the code please.